# Get the Last SMS Sent using ContentObserver

Tags: android, sms

Does this Code will Work on Any Device/Android Version since Froyo 2.2 :

```
 public class SmsObserver extends ContentObserver {
   private String Name;
   private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
   public SmsObserver(Handler handler , Context ctx) {
    super(handler);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        context = ctx;
        initialPos = getLastMsgId();
}

    private Context context;
    private static int initialPos;
    private static final String TAG = "SMSContentObserver";
    private static final Uri uriSMS = Uri.parse("content://sms");



    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        queryLastSentSMS();
    }

    public int getLastMsgId() {

        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        int lastMsgId = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        Log.i(TAG, "Last sent message id: " + String.valueOf(lastMsgId));
        return lastMsgId;
    }

    protected void queryLastSentSMS() {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Cursor cur =
                    context.getContentResolver().query(uriSMS, null, null, null, null);

                if (cur.moveToNext()) {

                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)
                        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                    String myDeviceId = tm.getDeviceId();
                    String myTelephoneNumber = tm.getLine1Number();

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int seconde = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                    try {

                        String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
                        String reformated_body =
                            Normalizer.normalize(body, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll(
                                "[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");

                        if (initialPos != getLastMsgId()) {
                            myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);        

                            getDisplayNameFromPhoneNo(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
                            final String finalTxt = context.getResources().getString(R.string.txtSMSSent) + " " + Name + " " +  cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")) + "  "  + context.getResources().getString(R.string.txtSMSMessage) + reformated_body;
                            Log.i(TAG, "Reformated Body : " + reformated_body);

                            Log.i("account", myDeviceId);
                            Log.i("date", day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " "
                                + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconde);
                            Log.i("sender", myTelephoneNumber);
                            Log.i("receiver", cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
                            Log.i("message", reformated_body);
                           if(!cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")).equals(Gever)){

                            // Then, set initialPos to the current position.
                            initialPos = getLastMsgId();
                        }
                    }} catch (Exception e) {
                        // Treat exception here
                    }
                }
                cur.close();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    public void getDisplayNameFromPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        ContentResolver localContentResolver =  context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor contactLookupCursor =  
           localContentResolver.query(
                    Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
                    Uri.encode(phoneNo)), 
                    new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, PhoneLookup._ID}, 
                    null, 
                    null, 
                    null);
        try {
        while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
            String contactName = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String contactId = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup._ID));
            Log.d("LOGTAG", "contactMatch name: " + contactName);
            Log.d("LOGTAG", "contactMatch id: " + contactId);
            Name = contactName;
            }


        } finally {
        contactLookupCursor.close();
        } 
    }

  }//End of class SmsObserver
```

I received One report from someone that say its does not Work , for me , its working fine , so this : "content://sms" is the Same for All Android Version ?